# Pivoting previously xml data via SQL query throws error

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I have data in table as below where value column data is quite big, like unstructured text:

http://s3.pdfconvertonline.com/convert/p3r68-cdx67/78gbs-hvj2r.html

The characters which you find in date like `&amp` and `&nbsp` are present and this is just for 2 small records, actual data is quite bigger which is why i use pivot xml as the IDs are 300 in real data set.

The Heading and Value columns were initially HTML data for each ID which is now split on basis of heading and corresponding value in html using xmltype parsing.
Now we have data in the 2 columns split.

I need to pivot this, i.e. the Heading column values which are constant for ever id to become column headers and the respective values to come below as rows.

When I run the pivot query it throws error:

```
select * 
from data 
pivot xml (max(id) for heading in (select heading from data));
```

> An error occurs in XML parsing.
> Entity reference is not well formed.
> XML Parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
> Check if document to be parsed is valid.

Could the error be because of these special characters?

Comment: rewrite by adding more parentheses such as `...pivot xml ( max(id) for heading in (select heading from data) )`, and please prefer text data instead of images. At least I personally cannot see them unless google indexes them within the image seach :)

Comment: I was trying to put text data but editor is converting it to image.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan i have changed data to text now.